# Microsoft Graph get events from multiple calendrers

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm using the calenderView endpoint to get events.
My problem is that I have about ten calendars to call at the same time, and so I often get 429 (To Many Requests). My solution was to add a delay between the requests. This is working, but the experience is awfully bad. Is there any solution to request events from multiply calendrers in one call?

Comment: You can try [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) and make a single call and get events for different calendars but you may see throttling issues using this way.

Comment: Let me share the best practice - consider using [Microsoft Graph pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) when you deal with huge amount of data, specially handling calendar items. This way you can handle good amount of data, avoid throttling as well.